# Why drop shadow filter does not work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, svg, cross-browser, dropshadow

I use this code for IE and other browsers but it's not working in IE.

**HTML part**

```
<svg height="0" width="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="drop-shadow">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.2"/>
        <feOffset dx="12" dy="12" result="offsetblur"/>
        <feFlood flood-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"/>
        <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode/>
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </feMerge>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

**Css part**

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=12, OffY=12, Color='#444')";
```

Comment: Please specify which version of IE you're using

Comment: Internet explorer 11, 10, and 9

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because for this filter you have to write in CSS:

```
filter: url(#drop-shadow);
```